# Are the tangent spaces alone enough to determine a differentiable manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm new to differential geometry. I'm aware there are theorems to describe Riemannian manifolds through fundamental forms. But I'm wondering, for a general smooth manifold, not necessarily equipped with more structures, if I know the tangent spaces at each point in a local chart, is it enough to determine the manifold locally already? Intuitively it seems just finding solutions to a system of first-order PDEs. But I'm not too sure. To make it intuitive, let's say the $m$-manifold is in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $m<n$. Extrinsic explanations are also welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate? If you assume you have local charts that are compatible with each other, then you have everything you need. Are you asking whether there is some way to define a manifold using only tangent spaces but no coordinate charts?

Comment: @Deane Perhaps using the word "chart" in my question raises confusions. What I meant is, without going into curvatures and other more involved concepts, by only knowing the tangent spaces in a neighborhood, can I know the manifold in that neighborhood already? Assuming I also know an initial point in that neighborhood. Is this purely an integrability problem? Or is it more subtle, more complicated?

Comment: Curvature plays no role in the definition of a manifold. I'm still confused. Could you say more about what your starting point is in your hypothetical definition of a manifold?

Comment: @Deane At this point, the concepts I have are smooth manifolds and the tangent spaces. Nothing more. I want to determine the equations of a $m$-manifold in $R^n$. Can I do that if I know the coordinates of one point on the manifold, and all the tangent spaces in a neighborhood around that point? So nothing intrinsic has to be involved here. Just extrinsic is all fine.

Comment: I'm under the impression that OP is looking for the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)#Formulation_using_vector_fields).

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks! That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: It seems perhaps there is a missing assumption: Is your given manifold assumed to be a *submanifold* of another given manifold?

Comment: @IvoTerek, good call.

Comment: @Lee That makes its appearance at the end of the question. Without an ambient space, I have no idea how OP would "know the tangent spaces."

Comment: @TedShifrin Yeah, that's just what I was wondering but I missed that thing at the end.